# has_one belongs_to association attribute validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, devise

I use devise for user authentication. Have two models `User` and `Profile` which are associated to each other like this

```
  #app/model/user.rb
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
    enum role: [:admin, :seller, :buyer]
  end

 #app/model/profile.rb
  class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
  end
```

As you can see I have also role for users.

Here is forms for registrations of both models.

```
  #user registration form
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.last(2) %>
    <%= f.input :mobile_number, required: true, autofocus: true  %>
    ...
  <% end %>

  #profile registration form 
  <%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
    ...
    <% if current_user.seller? %>
      <%= f.input :location, required: true %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.input :company_code, required: true %>
    <% end %>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

**Problem**

When current user is `seller` I need to validate presence of `:location` , when user is `buyer` then validate presence of `:company_code`.
How can I achieve that? I appreciate any helps , Thanks!

Comment: Is `location` is the attribute in the profile table ?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza nope its attribute of profiles table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validates` method accepts `if` option:

```
# app/model/profile.rb
  class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user    
    validates :location, presence: true, if: "user.seller?"
    validates :company_code, presence: true, if: "user.buyer?"
  end
```

Also, `current_user.role == "seller"` is obsolete. Rails automatically sets up additional methods in model for enum option values, therefore you may just write: `current_user.seller?`, etc.

Comment: @arm2pro you welcome. If my answer solved your issue, please don't forget to mark it as accepted